# AsyncTask: onPostExecute runs twice?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am running async task to load results from a server. I am using SearchView to pass the query term. Then using my own API to fetch the data. I am confused on why the AsyncTask outputs the data twice.

```
 mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(final String query) {
            linearLayout.removeAllViews();
            new Search(query, linearLayout).execute();

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            linearLayout.removeAllViews();
            return false;
        }
    });




private class Search extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Business>> {

    String query;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;

    public Search(String query, LinearLayout linearLayout) {
        this.query = query;
        this.linearLayout = linearLayout;
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Business> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        YelpApi yelpApi = new YelpApi(getString(R.string.yelp_consumer_key), getString(R.string.yelp_consumer_secret), getString(R.string.yelp_token), getString(R.string.yelp_token_secret));
        HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("term", query);
        parameters.put("sort", "2");
        parameters.put("limit", "5");
        return yelpApi.searchLocation("North Hills, CA", parameters);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Business> businesses) {
        for (int i = 0; i < businesses.size(); i++) {
            TextView mTextView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            mTextView.setText(businesses.get(i).getName());
            mTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            linearLayout.addView(mTextView);
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I run the search, two instances of the data is displayed. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What's the size of `businesses` ?

Comment: try to return true inside onQueryTextSubmit() method as you are handling it yourself

Comment: @satyenudeshi between 1 - 40

Comment: @DurgeshPatel that did not work.

Comment: @safaiyeh did you find answer to your question? i am facing the same issue. only onPostExecute gets called twice.

Answer (score 2):

Change your Query Search Listner to something like this

```
 mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(final String query) {
            linearLayout.removeAllViews();
            new Search(query, linearLayout).execute();

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            linearLayout.removeAllViews();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Hope it will work

Comment: the number of data displaying in your UI is equal to businesses arraylist size in the post execute ?

Comment: Sorry. the array list outputted twice.

Comment: So,It means now your able to trace the problem.

Comment: No, changing the return statement to true did not give me different results.